# Objective C - Add UIView to superview of UIView custom class programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I have an XIB for my `UIViewController`. Above my `ViewController` I want to add a `UIView` **Custom Class**.

Now I need a **dark view** between the `UIViewController` and my Custom `UIView`.

I wanted to implement the **Dark View** inside the `UIView` **custom class** using

`[self.superview addsubview: _darkView]`

I tried to do this but it doesn't seem to work ...

You can tell me how to solve this thing programmatically by working only from my uiview custom class ? Sorry for the stupid question but I can't solve this thing

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add subview on window

```
   [self.window addSubview: _darkview];
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: with "Window" the dark view cover UIViewController

Comment: If you want to add from customClass then you can add directly like this:
[self addsubview: _darkView]